# Wpf: ContentControl.AddChild(Object) method

Tags: c#, wpf

ContentControl only contains an object, it can be any CLR object, so what is the purpose of its AddChild method, am I wrong saying that ContentContol.Content property gets and sets its single child object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source code of the function:

```
/// <summary> 
///  Add an object child to this control
/// </summary> 
protected virtual void AddChild(object value) 
{
    // if conent is the first child or being cleared, set directly 
    if (Content == null || value == null)
    {
        Content = value;
    } 
    else
    { 
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.ContentControlCannotHaveMultipleContent)); 
    }
}
```

As you can see, it does the exact same thing that `Content` property does. But being virtual, means that you can override it and charge its behavior.

Source: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentControl@cs/1/ContentControl@cs